# jquery replace .live by .on

Tags: jquery, html

I have no idea why my close button won't work. I tried with `.close`, `#login-box`, `#btn_close`, `.btn_close`, `#close`, `.login-box`, etc thanks. Sorry if I ask this kind of question jQuery is new for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(function () {
        // Getting the variable's value from a link 
        var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

        //Fade in the Popup and add close button
        $('#login-box').fadeIn(300);

        //Set the center alignment padding + border
        var popMargTop = ($('#login-box').height() + 24) / 2;
        var popMargLeft = ($('#login-box').width() + 24) / 2;

        $('#login-box').css({
            'margin-top': -popMargTop,
            'margin-left': -popMargLeft
        });

        // Add the mask to body
        $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
        $('#mask').fadeIn(300);

        return false;
    });

    // When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
    $('body').on('click', '.close', function) {
        $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
            $('#mask').remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
    <a href="#" class="close"><img src="close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" id="close" /></a>
    <a class="forgot" href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: how to resolve my problem .... $('body').on('click', '.close', function) {  isnt working

Comment: i'll post my code on jsfidle

Comment: `function()` missing `)` Line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your click handler

This code...

```
// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('body').on('click', '.close', function) {
    $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $('#mask').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Should be

```
// When clicking on the button close or the mask layer the popup closed
$('body').on('click', '.close', function(e) {  // <-- pay attention here
    $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $('#mask').remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

**Tip:** Also consider using `e.preventDefault()` to disable default behaviour

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- right here

    $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300, function () {
        $('#mask').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error , missing a `(`

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function) {
   // code removed for clarity
});
```

Should be:

```
$('body').on('click', '.close', function() {
                                      //^ missing brace    
});
```

Make sure to check your browser console for errors. You should see a syntax error thrown